# Extract a column based on its contents CSV python

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas, extract

I have a csv file like below

```
h1,h2,h3
1 year,homo sapiens,fibrous tissue
3 minutes,homo sapiens,fibrous tissue
2 hours,homo sapiens,epithelial tissue
```

I'm trying to get just that column which has the string I provide in it. For example, if I say year, the entire column needs to be appended into a list like [1 year,3 minutes,2 hours]. I'm totally lost on how to proceed. I really appreciate any help.

EDIT: The issue with this is, the data can be in any column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a list comprehension and a combination of `any` and `str.contains`:

```
In [183]:
# filter the columns for only those that contain our text of interest
cols_of_interest = [col for col in df if any(df[col].str.contains('year'))]
cols_of_interest
Out[183]:
['h1']
In [184]:
# use the list as a column filter
df[cols_of_interest]
Out[184]:
          h1
0     1 year
1  3 minutes
2    2 hours
```

So this tests if `any` value in the column contains the text of interest by calling the vectorised `str` method [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains).

It would be easy to wrap the list comprehension into a function that returned the list:

```
In [185]:

def cols_contains(text):
    return [col for col in df if any(df[col].str.contains(text))]

df[cols_contains('year')]
Out[185]:
          h1
0     1 year
1  3 minutes
2    2 hours
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If it is in multiple columns, can we in anyway specify column name?

Comment: You can filter the columns also like `filtered = [col for col in df if 'text' in col]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
f=open('your_file.csv','r')

x=[]
for i in f:
    x.append(i)


"first column"

for i in range(len(x)):
    print x[i].split(',')[0]
```

Output 
h1

1 year

3 minutes

2 hours

```
"Second Column"


for i in range(len(x)):
    print x[i].split(',')[1]
```

Output:

h2

homo sapiens

homo sapiens

homo sapiens

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful but does not solve my problem. I'm sorry I didn't explain it well. I have a very weird file that has multiple columns with same header. I need to parse through them and extract only that column that has a given string.

Comment: Could you please add sample data in your question